# FFMPEG - Display per frame information for an AV1 encoded video

Tags: ffmpeg, bitrate, video-codecs

So I am trying to view per frame information for an AV1 encoded video using ffplay with the following command:

```
ffprobe -show_entries frame=pict_type,pkt_size,pkt_pts_time -select_streams v -of csv=p=0 `encoded.ivf`
```

When I use this command for an H264 or H265 encoded video it works fine. However, for AV1 encoded videos the packet sizes are zero as shown below

```
0,I
0,P
0,P
0,P
.....
```

Is there a particular reason behind that ? or AV1 codec is still relatively new and FFMPEG does not have proper support for it.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't know if it's a bug or a feature... But it looks like packet size can be found under `packet` and not under `frame`. Try: `ffprobe -show_entries frame=pict_type:packet=size,pts_time -select_streams v -of csv=p=0 encoded.ivf`. (I don't know if the output data is valid)

Comment: It works perfectly now and shows the packets sizes now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a bug in the bundled `dav1d` codec or the code that glues it with `ffmpeg`/`ffprobe`. If you use older releases e.g. 4.4.1 or `ffmpeg` that is built without `dav1d` but with `libaom-av1` instead,

```
ffprobe -show_entries frame=pict_type,pkt_size,pkt_pts_time -select_streams v -of csv=p=0 `encoded.ivf
```

works as expected.